Variance of MLE's in mixture distribution
I am studying mixture models, and I am interested in calculating the variance of the estimators using maximum likelihood. How is the variance calculated in this case? I already implemented the EM algorithm to estimate the parameters of my distribution
$$
f(x) = p_1 \lambda_1 e^{-\lambda_1 x} + \cdots +  p_k \lambda_k e^{-\lambda_k x}
$$
I had thought about calculating the observed information matrix and from there estimating the variance, but it seems a bit laborious and difficult, is there any other simpler method to obtain the variance of the MLE's? I appreciate any suggestions or references.

Derive the information matrix and use standard asymptotic distribution for MLE
It should be possible to derive the score function and information matrix from your model and then use the connection to the inverse-information to estimate the variance (using the asymptotic distribution of the MLE).  This requires you to derive the score function and Hessian matrix of the log-likelihood function for your model.  To facilitate analysis, we define the shorthand:
$$\boldsymbol{\phi}_i \equiv (\phi_{i,1},...,\phi_{i,k})
\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad 
\phi_{i,r} \equiv \log p_r + \log \lambda_r - \lambda_r x_i,$$
with related derivatives:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \phi_{i,r}}{\partial p_r} 
&= \frac{1}{p_r}
\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad 
\frac{\partial \phi_{i,r}}{\partial \lambda_r} 
= \frac{1}{\lambda_r} - x_i. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$
Using this shorthand, your log-likelihood function is:
$$\begin{align}
\ell_{\mathbf{x}}(\boldsymbol{p}, \boldsymbol{\lambda})
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \ell_{x_i}(\boldsymbol{p}, \boldsymbol{\lambda}) \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \log (p_1 \lambda_1 e^{-\lambda_1 x_i} + \cdots +  p_k \lambda_k e^{-\lambda_k x_i}) \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \log (\exp(\log p_1 + \log \lambda_1 - \lambda_1 x_i) + \cdots + \exp(\log p_k + \log \lambda_k - \lambda_k x_i)) \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \log (\exp(\phi_{i,1}) + \cdots + \exp(\phi_{i,k})) \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \text{logsumexp}(\phi_{i,1}, \cdots, \phi_{i,k}) \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \text{logsumexp}(\boldsymbol{\phi}_i). \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$
Taking $\text{soft}_r$ to be the softmax function with index $r$, the log-likelihood has derivatives given by:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \ell_{\mathbf{x}}}{\partial p_r}(\boldsymbol{p}, \boldsymbol{\lambda})
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{p_r} \text{soft}_r(\boldsymbol{\phi}_i), \\[12pt]
\frac{\partial \ell_{\mathbf{x}}}{\partial \lambda_r}(\boldsymbol{p}, \boldsymbol{\lambda})
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \bigg( \frac{1}{\lambda_r} - x_i \bigg) \text{soft}_r(\boldsymbol{\phi}_i), \\[12pt]
\frac{\partial^2 \ell_{\mathbf{x}}}{\partial p_r \partial p_s}(\boldsymbol{p}, \boldsymbol{\lambda})
&= - \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{p_r p_s} \text{soft}_r(\boldsymbol{\phi}_i) \text{soft}_s(\boldsymbol{\phi}_i), \\[12pt]
\frac{\partial^2 \ell_{\mathbf{x}}}{\partial p_r \partial \lambda_s}(\boldsymbol{p}, \boldsymbol{\lambda})
&= - \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{p_r} \bigg( \frac{1}{\lambda_s} - x_i \bigg) \text{soft}_r(\boldsymbol{\phi}_i) \text{soft}_s(\boldsymbol{\phi}_i), \\[12pt]
\frac{\partial^2 \ell_{\mathbf{x}}}{\partial \lambda_r \partial \lambda_s}(\boldsymbol{p}, \boldsymbol{\lambda})
&= - \sum_{i=1}^n \bigg( \frac{1}{\lambda_r} - x_i \bigg) \bigg( \frac{1}{\lambda_s} - x_i \bigg) \text{soft}_r(\boldsymbol{\phi}_i) \text{soft}_s(\boldsymbol{\phi}_i) \\[12pt]
&\quad \ - \mathbb{I}(r=s) \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \bigg( \frac{2}{\lambda_r} - x_i \bigg) \text{soft}_r(\boldsymbol{\phi}_i). \\[12pt]
\end{align}$$
This gives you all the elements of the Hessian matrix for your log-likelihood function, which should then allow you to find the actual and estimated inverse-information for your problem, which then allows you to appeal to the standard formula for the asymptotic distribution of the MLE.  I will leave the rest as an exercise for you.

inverse-information  Cox&Barndorff-Nielsen have named that formation!
